# does Jekyll have multi-language support?

Tags: ruby, markdown, jekyll, static-site

Actually, I bumped into the problem, that I can not locally compile site with jekyll. I receive this error when trying to add any characters not from 'standard' (English) ones (I don't even know how to characterize those as I still use Unicode which includes all of those).

```
Generating... error: incompatible encoding regexp match 
    (UTF-8 regexp with IBM866 string). Use --trace to view backtrace
```

I tried **different languages letters: German, Polish, Ukrainian**/Russian (ä ü ß ę ł є ї л), but result is always the same -- **error**.

I have this one setup in jekyll configuration (_config.yml). My local version of Ruby is 1.9.3 (and I really need only local version as use precompiled files approach - not jekyll-server on the side).

```
encoding: UTF-8
markdown: redcarpet
```

*(also tried markdown: maruku)*

I guess, that's really more Ruby-related error, because when I use listed characters in title

```
---
title: ä ü ß ę ł є ї л
---
```

it works great (and those characters live great in compiled pages), but not when they are added into the page body to parse. But still, *I am not Ruby developer and not the one who would easily locate the place to solve the thing in sources.*

If such characters use is not possible, then it makes Jekyll use pretty limited.

Comment: Could [this](https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll/issues/188) be similar to the problem you're having? If not, could you give us the backtrace (with `--trace`)?

Comment: Oh, actually, you've saved my life! :) I was really starting to loose my beliefs to open-source software...
+1 for pushing me closer to the answer! (I should have tried the trace earlier). Answering the question...
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Actually, thanks to Rafal Chmiel, it became clear what's the problem.
It was caused by [jekyll rss-**plugin**](https://github.com/agelber/jekyll-rss), which (seems) can not deal with other languages but English only.

I've added [issue into github](https://github.com/agelber/jekyll-rss/issues/4).
Just *stopped to use that plugin at the moment*.

This can be useful for any other user who uses **any other plugins** which can cause some other errors.

Just try to **trace** Jekyll to see what really happens:

```
jekyll build --trace
```

---

updated:

some more investigations shown that the problem inside the plugin is Maruku markdown parsing method. Actually, it causes the error, as the rss-plugin uses that code by default as I understand (even if any other 'markdown: ...' method selected in Jekyll setting).

I tried:

```
markdown: maruku
```

(without any plugins) and got exactly the same problem, which tells me something like '**Multilingual support by Jekyll is not available when using maruku markdown transformation**' at the moment.

---

**one more update**:

some further investigations did show a problem with **actually, Jekyll parser**. The way why my "title: [not-standard-unicode-characters]" worked is because of my editor *inserted BOM in the beginning of the file*: redcarpet then does not process the head part as a head part but just as some text and just generates the text as usual text.

However, when *I removed the BOM*, then the **new error** (different from the one above, but also **encoding-related**) appeared:

```
... test21.markdown: invalid byte sequence in UTF-8
... gems/jekyll-1.2.1/lib/jekyll/excerpt.rb:110:in `scan': invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 (ArgumentError)
```

header text is:

```
---
layout: post
title: український заголовок
---

український текст
some other text
```

I have added the issue request into [Jekyll github](https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll/issues/1624).

*Generally, that makes me curious is that because I am the first who ever tried to use Jekyll for sites with not only standard English content?!! Am I? Otherwise, such errors would be strange behaviour. No?*

---

**update:**

After speaking ["with" Jekyll here](https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll/issues/1624#issuecomment-26024376), the way to deal with multi-language characters is to use **HTML entities**, like this:

```
---
title: "&#1091;&#1082;&#1088;&#1072;&#1111;&#1085;&#1089;&#1100;&#1082;&#1080;&#1081;"
---
```

**wrapping them in quotes**.

Also, Jekyll's team thought is:

> Once v1.3 comes out, try assigning encoding: "utf-8" in your
>   _config.yml and trying without the HTML entities. It should correct itself (hopefully).

Comment: Actually, unfortunately, "the story" is not finished. All mentioned above is actual. Besides, there really seems a problem with Jekill natively. I've updated the answer above one more time...